# How to write a Bash script / command that shows the range of 500-511 HTTP server errors in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a bash script that will list and count the number of HTTP: 500 - 511 web error inside this file "ccc2022-02-19.txt"
Inside every file there are several 500 errors ranging from HTTP 500, 501, 502, 503 up to 511.

Within the directory where this files are , there are 4 different type of files listed there daily but I am only interested on the files that starts with "ccc" because they are listed daily for example "ccc2022-02-19.txt", "ccc2022-02-20.txt" etc

Below is an example of the file content "ccc2022-02-19.txt"

```
10.32.10.181    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:04 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  500     73      N       0       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:06 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  501     73      N       0       h
10.32.42.249    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:27 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  500     73      N       1       h
10.32.10.181    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:34 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  302     73      N       0       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  503     73      N       1       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  502     73      N       1       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  502     73      N       1       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  504     73      N       1       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  511     73      N       1       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  508     73
```

I have tried using this command

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i>=500 && $i<=511){print $i}}}' ccc2022-02-19.txt
```

which listed the numbers 500 -511 but I'm afraid that it is not giving only the HTTP response but grepped other number too like **500**23,  **503**893 found inside the file.

To be specific, I just want to see only the HTTP errors. Please note that the file content above is just an example......

Comment: you've stated concerns about your code not working for strings like `50023` and `503893` but there are no such strings in your sample inputs; consider updating the question to include a more representative set of data, to include these other strings you're worried about; also consider updating the question to show the exact (wrong) output generated by your code as well as the (correct) expected output

Comment: Nope , I don’t want it to search for  50023 because in that number (50023)you have 500 so the command filters that too and I wouldn’t want that.  I just need only the HTTP 500s… I don’t know how to rephrase the question so you’d understand. It’s unfair to give me a bad rating because you didn’t understand my question. Hopefully others will

Comment: I'm not sure *you* understand your issue; you've accepted an answer that has nothing to do with your question; I never said your code needs to search for `50023` ... *you* voiced a concern that *your* code might search for `50023`, but you don't provide any sample data to support this concern; I would suggest you review [How to create a minimal, reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then consider updateing your question accordingly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should achieve what you want. Please guys always try to read the description before concluding that he asked a stupid question. It is actually clear!!

```
awk '{print $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $11 " " $12}' ccc2022-02-21.txt | grep 500 | wc -l
```

This experiment was done in reference to the file output he provided above and i tested this and it worked! This was a brilliant question in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple `awk` script:

```
awk '$12 ~ /5[[:digit:]]{2}/ && $12 < 512 {print $12}' input.txt
```

#### Explanation

`$12 ~ /5[[:digit:]]{2}/`   Field #12 match 5[0-9][0-9]

`$12 < 512`                 Field #12 less than 12

`$12 ~ /5[[:digit:]]{2}/ && $12 < 512` (Field #12 match 5[0-9][0-9]) AND (Field #12 less than 12)

`{print $12}`               Print field #12 only if 2 conditions above are met

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **all** lines look like the sample (ie, the http error code is always in the 12th white-space delimited field):

```
$ awk '$12>= 500 && $12<=511 {print $12}' ccc2022-02-19.txt
500
501
500
503
502
502
504
511
508
```

If this doesn't work for all possible input lines then the question should be updated with a more representative set of sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this script might help

```
#!/bin/bash

ccc=500
while [ $ccc -le 511 ]
do 
  echo $ccc
  ccc=$(( $ccc +1 ))
  sleep 0.5
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much Emmanuel!! This is really helpful

But how can I be sure it will display only the HTTP:500 -511 errors and not other Radom numbers .. 5034, 50982, 500123 etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this:

```html
#!/bin/bash
CURRENTDATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
echo Today date is=${CURRENTDATE}
echo Looking for today file www${CURRENTDATE}.txt
echo "#####"

echo Start listing 500 response codes for file:ccc${CURRENTDATE}.txt
#awk '{print $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $11}' ccc${CURRENTDATE}.txt | grep 500
echo "I am not listing to reduce amount of lines per Ms-teams limit"
echo Completed listing 500 response codes for file:ccc${CURRENTDATE}.txt
echo "#####"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this out
I'm still open for other suggestions